# Code Igniter site moved to new server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I hope all of you are having a great week!

I have moved a code ignite site to a new server, When I moved it across I tested it here.

```
http://31.25.190.77/~freelanc
```

Where it works perfectly, so then I pointed the domain name at it.

```
http://www.freelanceentrysolutions.co.uk/
```

but not it doesn't work! Only the homepage works but if I click another link I get

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /supply-and-installations.html was not found on this
>   server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Any ideas here?

Kind Regards, Brad

SOLVED
I added this to the HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^freelanceentrysolutions\.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.freelanceentrysolutions\.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What error do you geT?

Comment: Both URLs show the same site for me.

Comment: I assume you are talking about other pages. When you click on other link it will show Internal document Error??

Comment: I updated the question, If you click a link on the navigation it will break!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to put index.php in all of your links?

```
/index.php/supply-and-installations.html
```

Try

```
http://www.freelanceentrysolutions.co.uk/index.php/supply-and-installations.html
```

or rewrite URLs to achieve this without using index.php

**MODIFICATIONS:**

If you are on apache put following in a .htaccess file and put that in root folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS / Image root Folder name(s)]|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Another good version is located here:

http://snipplr.com/view/5966/codeigniter-htaccess/

Comment: Thank you, but how would I go about that?

Comment: @BradHouston: modified the answer.. check and see if it works with you

Answer (score 0):

It work perfectly with http://www.freelanceentrysolutions.co.uk/index.php/supply-and-installations.html !

i think the `'index.php/supply-and-installations.html'` is problematic.

Comment: How can I remove the index.php?

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED! I added this to my HTAccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^freelanceentrysolutions\.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.freelanceentrysolutions\.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1
```